# Why is my Executor Service getting stuck when its close to completion every single time?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

To put simply, i have a a List userIds which could have a size of any number from 10k to 100k and those are user_ids, and my core logic is that for each user_id I call two different rest api end point and get those payloads, and then do a verfication operation among the payloads

I have used executor service for faster processing in the following way, i have split the records as batches and predefined 100 threads so that 1 thread could process (int)(userIds.size()/100) users

```
public void execute(List < String > userIds) {
    int numberOfThreads = 100;
    int WINDOW = (int) Math.floor(userIds.size() / numberOfThreads);
   
    int st = 0;
    int end = WINDOW;
   
    for (; st < userIds.size();) {
        int realStart = st;
        int realEnd = end;

        executor.execute(
            () - > {
                verify(realStart, realEnd, userIds) // this method has logic to verify users for the given start and end indexes from the userIds list

            }
        )
    
    st = end + 1;
    if (end + WINDOW >= userIds.size()) {
        end = userIds.size() - 1;
    } else {
        end = st + WINDOW;
    } // code to update the indexes realStart and realEnd for next 'n' batches
}
executor.shutDown();
try {
    System.out.println("Done");
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Done on a rope");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Lets say for 10k records when it is nearing completion, the code gets stuck, which makes me think if there are a few threads which are stuck inside the exectuorService, if so how do i workAround it, or is there any obvious flaw im making here?
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Something feels not right in your for loop. Where do you increase st?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri thanks for the comment, i actually skipped putting the incrementation loop here and replaced it with a comment in the code, i guess i will update the code with that part as well.

Comment: It still looks to me that you increase realstart and realend - but after the loop. And st is not increased at all. Am still confused why this should work.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri my bad updated the code, i could not copy paste so i had to type out the logic in the stackoverflow . so basically variables st and end keeps getting updated to another batch, every iteration.

Comment: Well, if the visible code is your real code you should have an endless loop. If it is not, I give up.

Comment: Agree with @HiranChaudhuri - currently the loop is endless. Unless you made a typo and st and end are updated within for-loop. Currently they are updated outside of the loop.

Comment: @SveKamenska thanks for pointing, that out, yes they are updated inside the loop, I have updated the code.

Comment: Why bother to batch? Why not process each user-id one at a time? If 100,000 user ids, why not submit 100,000 tasks to the executor service? Or is there some efficiencies to be gained from handling multiple at a time in your `verify` method?

Comment: So, if you have 100 users, then each thread will process 1 user in one go. If you have 500k users, then each thread will process 5000 users in one go. Is it intended solution that with increased load, you increase load on each thread? As it can be another way around: always process let's say 10 users: if you have 100 users, then only 10 threads will be activated and execute only once; if you have 500k, then all 100 threads will be activated and execute 500 times. Anyway, since you see that program gets stuck, it means we need to see verify() method

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything is OK with 100 threads and you system can handle it.

Then the issue can be within `verify()` method. Let's say, you have 10k users -> each thread processes 100 users at a time.

1. Logic of `verify()` method cannot handle it
2. `users Id's` are not unique within the list `userIds` and several threads are trying to process the same userId concurrently and maybe get dead-locked over some resources related to that user Id.
3. other issue with threads blocking each other, but again - it depends on your application logic

Note: `executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` only tells whether or not executor finished its processing, it does not force it to terminate after time has elapsed. According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), the correct way to finish would be :

```
executor.shutdown();
try {
    if (!executor.awaitTermination(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    } 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    executor.shutdownNow();
}
```

Another Note: you can use `while (st<userIds.size())` instead of half-empty `for (; st < userIds.size();)`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
1) verify method is a recusrive comparison of two json objects
2) The way i planned on using threads, was that even if userIds are not unique thread execution is not dependent on being unique, it simply executes it as a different userId
3) Yeah seems like this might be the issue, but  there is nothing in verify() method that' could cause this, one reason i could think of is maybe the api calls are taking time but i believe there is a timeout implemention there as well,  i.e those timeout after a little while.

Comment: Yeah and the reason i implemented the executor.awaitTermination that way was, for 100k, it takes 40 minutes to complete, so i wanted to terminate only if the threadExecution is completed.? maybe this is wrong approach as well? im not sure though

Comment: What i meant is that the daemon thread executes "executor.shutdown();" faster than the other threads get time to even start sometime, thats why my executor.awaitTermination is waiting for inifinity seconds, so that is comes out of await stage only when all userIds are completed.

Comment: So, inside your verify method you call external API to get json and then - compare that json? What stack you API is built on? Your application makes 100 concurrent calls to the external server. For example, Tomcat can handle 200 requests, MySQL - 151 - and these are maximum default numbers. So if API is standard, 1 server, with default configuration and you are not the only user - the issue can be there.